# Minimal clique edge cover vs minimalist (assignment-minimum) ones

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, clique, bipartite-graphs, covering-problems

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, a **clique edge cover** is a collection $C$ of subsets of $V$ such that each element $c$ of $C$ is a clique ($c \times c \subseteq E$) and $G$ is the union of these cliques ($E = \bigcup_{c\in C} c\times c$).

The cover is said to be minimal if $|C|$ is **minimal**, *i.e.* the number of cliques used to cover the graph is minimal.

Let us say that the cover is **minimalist** if $\sum_{c\in C} |c|$, *i.e.* the sum of clique sizes, is minimal.

(Is there a better term than minimalist here? Does it appear in the literature?)

**There exists minimal covers that are not minimalist covers.**

Consider for instance, the graph where $V=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $E$ is covered by $C = \{\{a,b,c\}, \{b,c,d\}, \{c,d,e\}\}$. This is a minimal covering of the graph, but not a minimalist one, since it is also covered by $\{\{a,b,c\}, \{b,d\}, \{c,d,e\}\}$.

***Question:***
**Is the converse true?** Is there any graph having a minimalist cover that contains more than the minimal number of cliques needed to cover it?

Comment: It turns out that minimalist covers are known as assignment-minimum coverings (which I will add to the question title), and that there are graphs for which no minimum clique covering is assignment-minimum, see ["Assignment-minimum clique coverings"](https://doi.org/10.1145/2133803.2275596) (Ennis, Fayle, Ennis, 2012).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a graph on vertex set $V_1\cup V_2\cup V_3\cup V_4\cup \{a,b,c,d\}$ where $|V_1|=|V_2|=|V_3|=|V_4|=n$. The edge set $E$ is covered by $C=\{V_1\cup\{a,c\},V_2\cup\{a,d\},V_3\cup\{b,c\},V_4\cup\{b,d\},\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$.

When $n$ is large enough, any minimalist cover must contain the four maximum cliques $V_1\cup\{a,c\}$ and so on, so it is not hard to show that $C$ is minimalist. However replacing the two edges $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ with a single clique $\{a,b,c,d\}$ results in less number of cliques.

Comment: Nice, thank you! The two coverings have the same sum of clique sizes; do you think we may go further and find a minimalist covering with a sum of clique size _strictly lower_ than the one of minimal coverings?

Comment: A friend just pointed me the following paper: [Assignment-minimum clique coverings](https://doi.org/10.1145/2133803.2275596) (Ennis, Fayle, Ennis, 2012) that seems to solve the question.